# Engine Error: Could not load library client

Tags: technical-issues, black-mesa

When I try to start black mesa, I get the message "Engine Error: Could not load library client", what should I do?

Comment: Do you have a more extensive error log?

Comment: @MBraedley No. I just get the message when I start the game.

Comment: What I've already done: Reinstall 2006&2007 Source SDK, tried the enable options menu fix, tried the gameinfo.txt fix, repaired steam.

Comment: A new update for the 2007 source SDK fixed this for now (at least for me).

Comment: You might want to put that as an answer. Also, mention the previous and current versions of the SDK, to help other people with a similar issue.